# How can i find a pattern in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a pattern and replace it with another
Suppose i have:

```
"Name":"hello"
```

And want to do this

```
Name= "hello"
```

Using python regex
The string could be anything inside double quotes so i need to find pattern "*": "*" and replace it with *="*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression,

```
^"\s*([^"]+?)\s*"\s*:\s*"?([^"]+)"?$
```

has two capturing groups:

```
([^"]+?)
```

for collecting our desired data. Then, we would simply `re.sub`.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTkrkT/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
import re
    
result = re.sub('^"\s*([^"]+?)\s*"\s*:\s*"?([^"]+)"?$', '\\1= "\\2"', '"  Name  ":"  hello   "')
print(result)
```

Comment: Your regexes would be more readable enclosed in single quotes: `regex = r'"\s*([^"]+)\s*"\s*:\s*"\s*([^"]+)\s*"'@` Also `([^"]+)` will gobble up trailing spaces before reaching `\s*`. Maybe `([^"]+?)`. Finally, you don't need to care about spaces on the right hand side, because if you strip them you alter the quoted string.

Comment: what if I want to do  "Name":[]--->Name=[]      ( []--->[ ] ) or it could be a value "Name":123---->Name=123

Comment: Why `Name= "hello"` and not `Name= "  hello   "`? In other words, why do you choose to strip spaces inside the right hand quotes? Shouldn't that quoted string be left unaltered?

Comment: no I mean what if there are numbers or brackets on the right side

Comment: Final nitpick (sorry). Your first two quoted strings need to be single quotes.

Comment: Yes ….Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Why not use this regex:

```
import re
s = '"Name":"hello"'
print(re.sub('"(.*)":"(.*)"', '\\1= \"\\2\"', s))
```

Output:

```
Name= "hello"
```

Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/e7rmES/1).

For strings containing more than one of those kind of strings, you would need to add some python code to it:

```
import re
s = '"Name":"hello", "Name2":"hello2"'
print(re.sub('"(.*?)":"(.*?)"', '\\1= \"\\2\"', s))
```

Output:

```
Name= "hello", Name2= "hello2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Python, this is as *simple* as:

```
s = '"Name":"hello"'

print(s.replace(':', '= ').replace('"', '', 2))
# Name= "hello"
```

Comment: This is fine if you have the pattern isolated, but if it's part of a larger document not so much.

Comment: How can i do it with regex....bcoz i need to replace it only if i get the pattern "*":"*"